# Which devices does Azure Spatial Anchors support?

Tags: azure, azure-spatial-anchors

Which devices does Azure Spatial Anchors support?

I would like to use Azure Spatial Anchors to support my mixed reality environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Azure Spatial Anchors enables developers to build apps on HoloLens, on iOS devices with ARKit support, and on Android devices with ARCore support; for iOS and Android this includes both phones and tablets.